# dplyr select using logical

Tags: r, dplyr

Can `select` in dplyr be used with a logical vector?

```
dat <- tbl_df(mtcars)
isNum <- sapply(dat, is.numeric)
select(dat, isNum)
```

> ```
> select(dat, isNum)
> ```
>
> Error in names(sel)[unnamed] <- sel[unnamed] : 
>     NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

Indices work: `select(dat,(1:ncol(dat))[isNum])` so why not a logical?

When I saw helper functions for select like `starts_with` `select(dat,starts_with("m"))` I assumed they would work with a logical ...

Comment: Possibly a [topic for `dplyr 0.3.1`](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/497): "In general, what is the best way to filter columns by some boolean condition in `dplyr`?"

Comment: I think you should post `select(dat,which(isNum))` as an answer (and even accept it if it seems like the best solution)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My answers would be:

- no ("Can select in `dplyr` be used with a logical vector?")

**evidence**: (1) your example, (2) the help page:

> ...: Comma separated list of unquoted expressions. You can treat
>             variable names like they are positions. Use positive values
>             to select variables; use negative values to drop variables.

Doesn't say anything about logical vectors.  Sorry.

- I don't know ("why not a logical?") -- 'just because' (I don't think anyone but the developer could really answer this).  You could put in a feature request ...

It's a little clunky, but

```
select_(dat,.dots=names(isNum)[isNum])
```

works (note that you need the `select_` variant to allow using a character vector).  But good old-fashioned

```
subset(dat,select=isNum)
```

seems to work fine too (unless it fails to play nicely with `dplyr` in some other way I haven't thought of).

If you look at the code of `dplyr:::starts_with`, you can see that it returns a vector of positions, not a logical vector

```
function (vars, match, ignore.case = TRUE) 
{
    stopifnot(is.string(match), !is.na(match), nchar(match) > 
        0)
    if (ignore.case) 
        match <- tolower(match)
    n <- nchar(match)
    if (ignore.case) 
        vars <- tolower(vars)
    which(substr(vars, 1, n) == match)
}
```

I was going to suggest that you try to modify this function to create an `is_numeric` equivalent, but I don't understand the underlying magic sufficiently well ...

Answer (score 30):

As Ben suggested:

`select(dat, which(isNum))`

Comment: This is really useful because we can put 'which' in front of any appropriate logical construction to return column numbers.

Answer (score 7):

As stated very clearly in other answers, the response to your specific question is **no**. You cannot use a logical vector in `dplyr::select()`.

However, in more recent versions of dplyr (v>=0.5.0) there is a new function that supports the use of *a predicate function to be applied to the columns or a logical vector* : [select_if()](https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/man/select_if.html).

Using `select_if` with a predicate function, your example could be simplified as follows:

```
tbl_df(mtcars) %>% dplyr::select_if(is.numeric)
```

But, you can also use `select_if` with a logical vector. This more directly addresses your use case above, which would look like the following:

```
dat <- tbl_df(mtcars)
isNum <- sapply(dat, is.numeric)
select_if(dat, isNum)
```

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays (dplyr 1.0 but probably also in early versions), it's also possible to use `where()` (a [tidyselect](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/language.html) helper) to directly apply the desired function without first running `sapply()`.

```r
library(dplyr)

select(mtcars, where(is.numeric))
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

This has an advantage compared to `select_if()` because you can simultaneously select columns that do not match the predicate function provided.

```r
library(dplyr)

starwars %>% 
  select(name, where(is.numeric))
#> # A tibble: 87 × 4
#>    name               height  mass birth_year
#>    <chr>               <int> <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1 Luke Skywalker        172    77       19  
#>  2 C-3PO                 167    75      112  
#>  3 R2-D2                  96    32       33  
#>  4 Darth Vader           202   136       41.9
#>  5 Leia Organa           150    49       19  
#>  6 Owen Lars             178   120       52  
#>  7 Beru Whitesun lars    165    75       47  
#>  8 R5-D4                  97    32       NA  
#>  9 Biggs Darklighter     183    84       24  
#> 10 Obi-Wan Kenobi        182    77       57  
#> # … with 77 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>